# Handling asynchronous data with mermaid-js in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, mermaid

So, I am working on a project where I need to get data from the DB **asynchronously** and then use that data to draw a **sequence diagram** using mermaid.js' markdown syntax.
But the problem that I'm facing is that apparently the sequence diagram is rendered in the UI during the initial loading time itself and then it shows the diagram as a simple HTML content. I tried the **setTimeOut()** to pause the **mermaid.initialize()** for a second or so and then execute it but it does not work as well.

However, if there are no backend calls to the db, i.e, the data is hard-coded then the sequence diagram works just fine.

I also tried keeping startOnLoad property as false, but again it shows the diagram as a simple HTML content.

Any idea on how to handle this particular use case?

### Case 1: When the data is hard-coded.

**.html file**

```
<div class="mermaid">
  sequenceDiagram
  {{final}}
</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
 selector: 'app-mermaid',
 templateUrl: './mermaid.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./mermaid.component.css']
})
export class MermaidComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }
 final:string = '';
 items=[
 { 
  source:"1",
  destination:"2",
  message:"Request from 1"
},
{ 
  source:"2",
  destination:"1",
  message:"Response from 2"
 }
]


ngOnInit(): void {
 mermaid.initialize({
  theme: "forest"
}
);

for(let i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
  this.final += `Node${this.items[i].source}->>Node${this.items[i].destination}: ${this.items[i].message};`
  }
 }
}
```

For this case, a sequence diagram is rendered in the UI:

[when data is hard coded, the sequence diagram is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ8VE.png)

### Case 2: When the data is received from a db.

Here, instead of calling data from a db, I have simply created a setTimeOut in my ngOnInit(), to imitate an asynchronous call.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
mermaid.initialize({
  theme: "forest"
}
);
setTimeout(() => {
  for(let i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
    this.final += `Node${this.items[i].source}->>Node${this.items[i].destination}: ${this.items[i].message};`
  }
},100)
```

}

Here, I get some svg error, I tried to solve it with and additional property in **initialize()** i.e;

```
mermaid.initialize({
  theme: "forest",
  startOnLoad: false,
}
```

But, this renders the string as it is. Somewhat like this.

*sequenceDiagram Node1->>Node2: Request from 1;Node2->>Node1: Response from 2;*

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please show some code. You'd need to consider your issue is very non-specific and many if not none would have experienced it the same way you do. Also the more details you provide, more eyes try to solve it.

Comment: Yes, I have added the code samples. Let me know if you can find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution to this. I used a **mermaid.init()** function along with a setTimeOut() of a second. It solves the issue for now.

This is what I did.

```
ngOnInit(){
  mermaid.initialize({
    theme: "forest",
    startOnLoad: false,
  }
  );
  setTimeout(() => {
    for(let i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
      this.final += `Node${this.items[i].source}->>Node${this.items[i].destination}: ${this.items[i].message};`
    }
  },1000)

   setTimeout(() => {
     mermaid.init()
   },1000)
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Do you found a better way to re-init by any chance? I'm trying to change the theme dynamically but it's a bit tricky :/